# Breaking out of Loop from within Callback Function in PHP

Tags: php, function, foreach, callback, break

For a project I am running a high amount of data throughput and need to chunk it to process it. This process is run several times for different users. All of that is working well. Occasionally though, the processing needs to throw a stop error to break out of the script gracefully (IE: Not using `die()` but instead log an error) and continue with next user's data.

Here is a very simplified version of my script. I know that this could be rearranged in this simplistic mode to remove the callback function in its entirety, but the actual script requires it to be setup like this.

```
<?php
$user_data = array(
    'User 1' => array(
        array(
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
        ),
        array(
            10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,
        ),
    ),
    'User 2' => array(
        array(
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
        ),
        array(
            11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
        ),
    ),
);
foreach($user_data as $data_chunks){
    foreach($data_chunks as $data_set){
        foreach($data_set as $data){
            myFunction($data, function($returned_data, $stop){
                if($stop){
                    //log error
                    break 2;
                }
                print $returned_data." ";
            });
        }
    }
}

function myFunction($data, callable $f){
    $stop = false;
    if($data>5){
        $stop = true;
    }
    $data_to_return = $data*2;
    $f($data_to_return,$stop);
}
?>
```

Php throws a fatal error for

> Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 2 levels

Comment: Have your function return a value early that indicates it needs to break.

Comment: @Cfreak Is it possible to return a value to a callback function? I didn't see any examples of that in PHP docs.

Comment: I've thought about using a global variable and checking it to continue or stop.

Comment: Use a try/catch block, and throw an exception in your callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you have myFunction return a value to indicate if looping should stop?

```php
foreach($user_data as $data_chunks){
    foreach($data_chunks as $data_set){
        foreach($data_set as $data){
            // V-- Collect return value below
            $returned_stop = myFunction($data, function($returned_data, $stop){
                if($stop){
                    //log error
                }
                print $returned_data." ";
            });
            if ($returned_stop) { // <- Check to stop here
              break 2;
            }
        }
    }
}

function myFunction($data, callable $f){
    $stop = false;
    if($data>5){
        $stop = true;
    }
    $data_to_return = $data*2;
    $f($data_to_return,$stop);
    return($stop); // <- Return here
}
```

Comment: This should work, I will implement and test tomorrow. I kept trying to get the return from the callback function instead of the function called.